# Android: Calling setY with the SAME y position on a SeekBar twice moves it into two different locations?

Tags: java, android

When I click on a `Button`, that button is supposed to make a hidden `SeekBar` (visibility = "gone") visible at the coordinates (150, 150). However, the first time I click on that Button, the SeekBar is placed in a different location than the second time, as shown in the screenshots below:

**First Click**:

[image]

**Second Click**:

[image]

Below is my code:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="makeSeekbarVisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.changingimageviewwidth;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void makeSeekbarVisible(View v) {
        // Make the image preview box visible
        SeekBar seekbar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        seekbar.bringToFront();

        // Place the image preview box at a specified location
        seekbar.setX(150);
        seekbar.setY(150);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [setX/Y](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setY(float)) documentation:

> Sets the visual y position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to setting the translationY property to be the difference between the y value passed in and the current top property.

It is happening because the initial visibility of the view is **GONE**. So when calling **setY** for the first time, the view is not drawn yet (checkout [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)) so the top property is 0. After a while the view is drawn and the top property is changed so the view is below the button; causing the y property to also change.

Timeline:

1. Activity started and views are drawn: **top=0, y=0**
2. Button is just pressed but the SeekBar not drawn yet: **top=0, y=150**
3. SeekBar is drawn: **top≃BUTTON_HEIGHT, y≃BUTTON_HEIGHT+150**
4. Button is pressed second time: **top≃BUTTON_HEIGHT, y=150**

Comment: How would I go about resolving this issue then?

Comment: I actually don't see your expected behavior. But if you want it as your second picture, wait for the view to be drawn using onGlobalLayoutListener (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15578844/6094503) and after that make calls to setX/Y.